# Why boolean condition in if statement of OpenGL should be avoid?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am a newbie in OpenGL, I have a question and must answer to my leader: "Why bool expressions like the one used in the above example should be avoided in if and if-else conditional statements". I must answer it tomorrow but I don't have any clue, any one can help me,
Thanks!
P/s: this code here:

```
void main ()
{
    vec4  color = texture2D ( tex , v_uv);

    if (color.r < 0.25)
        gl_FragColor =  texture2D (tex1 ,  v _uv);

    else
        gl_ FragColor =  texture2D ( tex2, v _uv);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because GPU's [don't like dynamic branching](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter34.html).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide the example, but I'm going to just make assumptions and say that branching on GPU can be a bad thing..

Different GPUs have support for different styles of branching though, so the impact depends on the code and your target's support (SIMD, MIMD, condition code branching, etc).

Depending on the type of branching (ie:  what conditions you are checking and what the resulting code is), other cores in the grid may end up waiting until the last completes it's if branch and rustling code.  So, if you have one core that went off and had to do some complicated stuff due to a condition being satisfied, then all cores will need to wait on said core.  This can really add up and reduce your performance...  But it depends on the target and code!